# Servant-like implementation with GADTs

Tags: haskell, gadt, servant

I'm reading the excellent [Why is servant a type-level DSL?](https://haskell-servant.github.io/posts/2018-07-12-servant-dsl-typelevel.html). I've got to the section where the problem with the implementation presented so far is that the number of captures in an `Endpoint` can vary and there is no way of implementing a total a link generating function without dependant types.

The `Endpoint` definition is:

```hs
data Method = Get | Post

data Endpoint = Static String Endpoint
              | Capture Endpoint
              | Verb Method
```

and example definitions are:

```hs
getHello :: Endpoint
getHello = Static "hello" (Capture (Verb Get))

twoCaptures :: Endpoint
twoCaptures = Capture (Capture (Verb Post))

noCaptures :: Endpoint
noCaptures = Static "hello" (Verb Post)
```

and the **non-total** link making function is:

```hs
linkTo :: Endpoint -> [String] -> Link
linkTo (Static str rest) captureValues  = str : linkTo rest captureValues
linkTo (Capture rest)    (c : cs)       = c   : linkTo rest cs
linkTo (Capture rest)    []             = error "linkTo: capture value needed but the list is empty" -- :-(
linkTo (Verb method)     _              = []
```

I'm intrigued by the following:

> Fortunately, GADTs can help here. We could turn `Endpoint` into a GADT
>   that tracks captures and then use some type-level computations to get
>   the type of the link-making function from our list of captures, as
>   well as define the link making function through typeclass instances
>   that would go through the captures and add an argument for each of
>   them ...  a GADT-based approach would work well (in addition to being more approachable) for very stable domains, and is not considered here because of the kind of flexibility we are asking for.

I'm interested in experimenting with the GADT approach however I could do with some hints for how to create a GADT which will *"track captures and then use some type-level computations to get the type of the link-making function from our list of captures"*

Can anyone give me some hints for how to get started with a GADT version. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Servant, but perhaps the quote was referring to some GADT like the following one. The idea is to define a type `Endpoint t` where `t` is of the form `String -> String -> ... -> Link` where all the string arguments correspond to the captures. Once this is done, then `toLink` is simply of type `Endpoint t -> t`.

I did not use type classes.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module ServantEndpoint where

type Link = [String]

data Method = Get | Post

data Endpoint t where
   Static :: String -> Endpoint t -> Endpoint t
   Capture :: Endpoint t -> Endpoint (String -> t)
   Verb :: Method -> Endpoint Link

linkTo :: Endpoint t -> t
linkTo e = go e []
   where
   go :: Endpoint t -> Link -> t
   go (Static str rest) l = go rest (str : l)
   go (Capture rest)    l = \s -> go rest (s : l)
   go (Verb _method)    l = reverse l
```

A small example:

```
test :: Link
test = f "capture1" "capture2"
   where f = linkTo (Capture (Static "static1" (Capture (Static "static2" (Verb Get)))))
-- output: ["capture1","static1","capture2","static2"]
```

Comment: (author of the post here) This is exactly what I had in mind. You'd want to expand this further if you were to add query parameters and what not, but this is very much the idea I had in mind. I hesitated to include code for it because it would have made the post a lot longer.

Comment: Thanks both really helpful as well as being cunning and clever,  At my current level of Haskell proficiency I couldn't have come up with that solution without your help. Is this a common GADT pattern? All the GADT examples I've seen are based on parsing expressions and I struggle to make the jump from those to this.

Comment: @NickAger I don't how much common it is, but probably it's fairly common. GADTs are a powerful and complex language feature: they are often used to encode some kind of invariant, so that the type checker enforces it. This, in general, can be a daunting task for the programmer. IMHO, only relatively few programmers have a solid understanding of invariants. And even in that case, encoding it in a GADT requires some creativity. GADTs are not that hard to be used, but they require some time and effort to be picked up. It's only a matter of experience.

Comment: @chi next naive question - what is the invariant that is being encoded in this GADT? Thanks.

Comment: Roughly, the invariant is that `linkTo` takes as many string arguments as the captures in the endpoint value.